# HBASE with Distributed File System?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, distributed-filesystem

Well its quite clear that HBASE is database that save its file in HDFS. Can HBASE even be integrated with other distributed file system? If yes, then what should be the underlying approaches?For example If I am using Hadoop with Ceph, then can HBASE save its data in CEPH fs.